# Installing nbextensions for Jupyter on AWS-GLUE local setup ( docker image ) - getting permission issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, local, aws-glue

I am trying to install nbextensions for my Jupyter notebook , but getting a user permission error . After reading through multiple websites ,  I have added --user, but the issue persists.

This is being run on a MACBook

Steps for setting this up :
Install Docker
Pull AWS - Glue image from Dockerhub
start the docker

> docker run -it -v ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws -v
> $JUPYTER_WORKSPACE_LOCATION:/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace/
> -e AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE_NAME -e DISABLE_SSL=true --rm -p 4040:4040 -p 18080:18080 -p 8998:8998 -p 8888:8888 --name  glue_jupyter_lab
> amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
> /home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh

The notebook is working and I am able to run code. However ,for ease of coding trying to install the NBExtensions, which is failing.

```
> sh-4.2$ jupyter contrib nbextension install --user Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/home/glue_user/.local/bin/jupyter-contrib", line 8, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
> line 264, in launch_instance
>     return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 845, in launch_instance
>     app.initialize(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
> line 235, in initialize
>     self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 685, in parse_command_line
>     return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 604, in initialize_subcommand
>     self.subapp.initialize(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
> line 235, in initialize
>     self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 685, in parse_command_line
>     return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 604, in initialize_subcommand
>     self.subapp.initialize(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 88, in inner
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
> line 239, in initialize
>     self.migrate_config()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
> line 165, in migrate_config
>     migrate()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line
> 245, in migrate
>     with open(os.path.join(env['jupyter_config'], 'migrated'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/glue_user/.jupyter/migrated'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really install NBExtensions on the docker image. I moved to using VSCode, which was a much friendly editor to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).